# StackOverflow exception occuring when running the java class

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have a class Test. When i run the program it throws Stackoverflow error.

**Class:**

```
public class Test {

   private Test test = new Test();
    
   public Test() {

      System.out.println("ijshfiksh");
   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
   }
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:5)
```

Can anyone tell my why this is happening?

Comment: What did you expect `private Test test = new Test();` to do?

Comment: This question is asked in a online test. I thought the answer will be something else. But when i ran it, The error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from here:

```
public class Test {
   private Test test = new Test();
   ...
}
```

You are creating an instance of `Test` inside `Test`: to build that `Test` instance, you have to build another instance of `Test`, which also requires an instance of `Test`, and so on

Comment: But isn't this the same concept as LinkedList. Which have Object inside Itself. So why is this different?

Comment: @tukeko yes, but a LinkedList wouldn't be initialized in the same way. It will be done in different parts of the code, so this mess wouldn't happen. The way it's done in this code, it will be done unconditionally and at the same time the object itself was created.

Comment: @tukeko in case of linked list, you initialize the field to `null`, and only when you want to add an element, you create that new node, which will have that private field set to null, until you insert another node

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new `Test` object, line 3 is called:

```java
private Test test = new Test()
```

This creates a new `Test` object, so line 3 is called again, and this repeats forever.

A StackOverflowError is a runtime error in java. It is thrown when the amount of call stack memory allocated by JVM is exceeded. And this is caused by the infinite recursion of the creation of `Test` objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

   //Each time you create a Test object, it creates another Test object, therefore the StackOverflow
   private Test test = new Test();
    
   public Test() {

      System.out.println("ijshfiksh");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
   }
}
```

Correct code:

```
public class Test {
    
   public Test() {

      System.out.println("ijshfiksh");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
   }
}
```